Howto debug sql_batch_completed with result abort? Broken connection diagnosis with extended events possible?
I've got some weird errors in one environment (read: not reproduceable on another VM with the same versions where the data is the same).
As the application uses OLEDB, I built a minimal failing example in C#.
I run an OLEDB command in C# with the provider MSOLEDBSQL (v18.6.7.0). It succeeds within one second. As soon as I built a Thread.Sleep(10) (to emulate actual processing of the data) in the read loop, it will fail. It seems to be a network error for now, but I'm wondering why I don't get more details from the SQL server...
The callstack from the extended events look like this:
sqldk!XEPackage0::CollectCPUCycleCountAction::Invoke
sqldk!XEPackage0::CollectFileTimeAction::Invoke
sqldk!XEPackage0::GetLastErrorAction::Invoke
sqldk!XeSosPkg::CollectTaskTimeActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectDatabaseNameActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectResponseRowsActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectSessionIdActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectSessionNtUsernameActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectTransactionIdActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectTransactionSequenceActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectTSqlFrame<XE_ActionForwarder>
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectTSqlFrameActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectTSqlStack<XE_ActionForwarder>
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectTSqlStackActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::sql_batch_completed::Publish
sqllang!CBatchTraceHelper::TracePostBatchEvent
sqllang!CLanguageExecEnv::OnExecError
sqllang!process_request
sqllang!process_commands_internal
sqllang!process_messages
sqldk!SOS_Task::Param::Execute
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks
sqldk!SchedulerManager::WorkerEntryPoint

It happens both on SQL Server 2019 and 2022 with the most recent CUs (2019: 15.0.4355.3).
I don't find some connection problem/closing related extended events...
Network trace with netsh trace is already done - it seems to be an actual network issue within VMware Distributed Firewall. As soon as this is disabled, the issue disappears. But this is about diagnosis options in SQL Server. I can only see abort, but haven't found a way to get details of "OnExecError".

Abort means either the client gave up (on command timeout) and requested an abort, or the server detected a broken connection and aborted. Why are you doing Thread.Sleep at all inside the read loop, and why not await Task.Delay which might be more amenable to holding open the connection.

Unfortunately that's a non-descript call stack, very generic error handling. You're better off doing a packet capture (if it's tcp/ip) from both sides, WireShark for example has an ok TDS interpreter.

Also why OleDb from C#, instead of the managed .NET SqlClient?

Thanks for the comments, I added answers to all three into the post.
